# JPA persist many to many Fetch=FetchType.Lazy

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I have a pretty standard scenario whereby I have a table of Employe and a table of Unite ewith . The two tables are related via a many to many relationship (ie. emoloye can have many unite and a unite can be applied to many employe) and subsequently I have a joining table called effectif_unite. The only two columns .
I have generated the entity classes (see below) and I have no problem persisting data to the employe and unite tables but I have failed miserably persist anything to the employe_has_unite .

// Method en Application Client

```
public void add(int mat, String grade, String fonction, int cnprs, int cin, String np, String adress, String tel, int disp, Date date, ArrayList uns) {
    Employe emp = new Employe();
    Grade gr = bean.grade_emp(grade);
    Fonction f = bean.fonction_emp(fonction);
    emp.setMatEmp(mat);

    emp.setNumGrd(gr.getNumGrd());
    emp.setNumFon(f.getNumFon());
    emp.setCnprs(cnprs);
    emp.setCin(cin);
    emp.setAdress(adress);
    emp.setTel(tel);
    emp.setNp(np);
    emp.setDispo(disp);
    emp.setDtRt(date);
    emp.setUniteList(uns); // i affect List<Unite> To employe here!!

    bean.add(emp);
    }

// DAO
public void add(Employe e,ArrayList<Unite> uns)
{  /* EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
et.begin();
em.persist(e);
et.commit();     */
EntityTransaction ett = em.getTransaction();
ett.begin();
EffectifUnite u=new EffectifUnite();

u.setUnite(uns.get(0));
u.setEmploye(em.find(Employe.class, 1));
EffectifUnitePK pk= new EffectifUnitePK();
pk.setMatEmp(em.find(Employe.class, 1).getMatEmp());
pk.setNumUnt(uns.get(0).getNumUnt());
u.setEffectifUnitePK(pk);


em.persist(u);
ett.commit();
}
```

Comment: What exception exactly do you receive. I can not see it in your question

Comment: ok but in which entity i can add Fetch=FetchType Lazy or Eager!

Comment: It seems to me, that you try to change an entity that you received from the JPA, detached it and now you try to use elements from this entity that defined as a `lazy` relation. But it is hard to say sonthing accurate without more information (e.g. entity definition etc.). Anything else would be guessing riddles.

Comment: yes it is true , i'm adding the entities

Comment: Where you get the list `uns` (code on the top) from. Check the IDs of the members in `uns`. Make sure that you have set `matEmp` in all members of `uns` to `emp` (e.g. `uns.get(0).setMatEmp(emp)`)

Comment: yes i edit the code but it is the same problem

Comment: i have a relation between Unite and employe so uns.get(0).setMat-emp(emp) it is  not correct ,i want  to insert data in Table effectif_unite  when i persist Entity employe Relation Many To Many

Comment: If you do not anything like `uns.get(0).setMatEmp(emp)` then your relation is broken, because your mapping says, that all `Unite` with `matEmp` is in the List `Employe.uniteList` - and no one else.

Comment: Is this the fourth time you are posting the same question? Delete the other ones if they represent the same question. How is the DAO annotated? How do you construct / inject it? Do you have any notion of transactions? Have you ever managed to make a successful transaction in a simpler scenario? What does it mean _6 down vote favorite 1_?

Comment: Thanks @drkunibar i solve the problem now  , you  can see the  method DAO Thanks again for all

Comment: In your code snippet you do it only for the first element of your lists (`..get(0)...`). I hope you paying attation to all elements of your lists ;-)